# Logging in with a Keycloak service account from a WildFly secure deployment

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I am running a web application packaged as WAR inside WildFly, with authentication configured via a [secure deployment](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#securing-wars-via-adapter-subsystem) managed by the Keycloak adapter subsystem.

The corresponding client in Keycloak is configured with a service account. Now, I'd like to send requests to Keycloak (and possibly other services) using the service account and associated roles.

1. What is the best way to obtain a token for authentication "as the service", i.e. using the service account?
2. Is there a way to access the client secret specified in the secure deployment definition from the runtime context of my WAR?
3. Am I doing things wrong? What is the optimal approach here?

Note that I still need to be able to authenticate requests from the web inbound to the service with Keycloak.